# java textarea and input to file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea

I'm having problems in my Java app. I wanted to transfer the texts in my `JTextArea` to a .txt file

for example
I inputted

```
"Hi
my name is george"
```

I want the outcome in my .txt file to be the same

but what happens is

```
"Himy name is george"
```

Here's my code

```
private void btnCreateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String filename,content;
    String[] ArrContent=new String[9999];
    int wordctr=0;

    try
    {
        if(txtFilename.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            lblRequired.setText("Required Field");
        }else
        {
            lblRequired.setText(" ");
            filename=txtFilename.getText()+".txt";
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(filename);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            if(txtContent.getText().contains("\r\n"))
                writer.write("\r\n");
            writer.write(txtContent.getText());
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think there is only a `\n` in the textarea. Try to change: `txtContent.getText().contains("\r\n")` to `txtContent.getText().contains("\n")`

Comment: thx for the reply... it's still the same results

Comment: Use [`JTextArea#write(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write(java.io.Writer)) instead

Comment: I am a little surprised that you have to manually detect it and write it. Can you provide a fully compilable example that reproduces the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry I just started java can u help me I didn't understand JTextAre#write(Writer)

Comment: @newbie07 Hit the link, `JTextArea` has `write` method that takes `Writer`

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`JTextArea#write(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29) instead...

```
String filename = txtFilename.getText()+".txt";
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(filename))) {
    txtContent.write(fw);
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

And make sure you making best efforts to close the resources that you create...

Comment: thx... although I can't understand the difference between what I did to what you did :D but it worked! thx

Comment: Instead of trying to loop through the text content of the `JTextArea` and write that to the `Writer`, I passed the `Writer` to the `JTextArea` and allow it to handle it...

Comment: oh.. hmm if I will do this the other way around will it be the same? instead of using FileWriter will I use FileReader?

Comment: Yes, `JTextArea` has a [`read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read(java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object)) method

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `System.lineSeparator()` to write a new line to a text file.

So try something like the following

```
if(txtContent.getText().contains("\r\n"))
            writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
```